# FB connect in Drupal6

Tags: blocks, social-network

I am working in drupal-6 trying to do facebook connect button.

I installed fboauth module sucessfully. now i also  got fb connect button and also able to connect successfully. now first time i allow application for this. it works successfully.  Now
When i logout from website as well as from Fb. then try to connect fb coonect it goes to app page after login. i want it directly goes to my website. when i logged in ..

Any body have idea?

Comment: This is either a bug or a misconfiguration of the module from your side. I would suggest reading the fboauth documentation  or posting this question to the fboauth issue queue http://drupal.org/project/issues/fboauth?categories=All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Problem. FB changes their structure of application. Not a bug